# page replacement algorithms comparision in C

Tags: operating-system

Can someone please help me with this question that was asked in my interview ?
Thanks in Advance :)

Implement a program in C language which compares performance of various page
­replacement algorithms. It
should take the following as input:

1. CPU address size in bits e.g. 64 bits.
2. Page size in bytes.
3. Physical memory size in bytes.
4. Length of page reference string.
5. Page reference locality factor which is a values between 0 to 1. It indicates what fraction
   of the pages in page string are repeatedly accessed.
6. Memory access time in ns.
7. Page swap time in ms.

Your program should suitably compare the performance of the following algorithms a) FIFO b) LRU c) Least Frequently Used d) Random.

Performance should be measured in terms of: a) Page fault rate and b) Effective memory
access time.

Comment: This looks more like a school assignment than an interview question. Either way, what have *you* tried so far to do so that isn't working for you?

Comment: I am sorry but i can't think how to proceed i mean i know all the terms but how will i calculate page fault rate,still figuring it out! can you help ?

Comment: Sounds like you should ask your instructor for help.

Comment: Okay no problem :D !!! Thanks anyways.